# Trigger after insert data update

Tags: sql-server

I have 3 tables Reservation, Ticket and Seat. They are connect like Reservation.code_of_ticket = Ticket.code and Ticket.number_of_seat = Seat.number. In table Ticket is attribute occupation, I need change it when I insert data to table Reservation. It is possible do it lihe this?

```
CREATE TRIGGER occupancy
ON Reservation
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    UPDATE Seat
    INNER JOIN Seat ON Seat.number = Ticket.number_of_seat 
    INNER JOIN Ticket ON Ticket.code = Reservation.code_of_ticket 
    SET occupancy = 'reserved'
    WHERE occupancy = 'free';
END
```

Comment: Did you try it? There are some problems with your code.  You are not referring to the "inserted" rowset.  That's where the new rows can be accessed by the trigger.  Plus, you refer to "Reservation." in your join predicate without a table reference.

Comment: @user1443098 All those problems indicate that Jana is a beginner and doesn't have much experience. I suggest that you identify these factors to give better guidance instead of just remarking the errors.

Comment: Why are you updating `Seat` table, when the field is on the `Ticket` table? It doesn't make sense to me, but that's what OP has stated... `In table Ticket is attribute occupation, I need change it when I insert data to table Reservation.`

Answer (score 3):

Your base logic is correct, the syntax is terribly wrong. When dealing with triggers, we use the special tables `inserted` and `deleted` which have the information of the data changes and have the same structure as the base table.
The trigger should look something like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER occupancy
ON Reservation
AFTER INSERT
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON;

UPDATE s --This is an alias for the table Seat
SET occypancy = 'reserved'
FROM Seat s --We can use FROM clauses like a normal SELECT
INNER JOIN Ticket t on s.number = t.number_of_seat --Is the seat number global or should you add a theater/auditorium number in your join logic?
INNER JOIN inserted i on t.code = i.code_of_ticket 
WHERE s.occypancy = 'free';
```